# How to uninstall visual studio code in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: software-uninstall, gdebi, visual-studio-code

Installed `Visual Studio Code` (64bit deb package) using the `gdebi` installer, now I want to uninstall it properly.

I tried the following to no avail -

- `remove installation` option in `gdebi` ----> does not work
- `remove` option from `Software Center` -----> does not work
- `sudo dpkg --purge code` ---->
  `dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove code which isn't installed`

Looks like I may have a broken package now. How do I get rid of it manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was my fault!

I installed VSCode using `umake` but wrongly assumed that I had used `gdebi`. I finally found out from the launcher file that the executable is in `Exec=/home/<username>/.local/share/umake/ide/visual-studio-code/bin/code`.

I just had to trigger `sudo umake --remove ide visual-studio-code` to get rid of it completely!

Comment: Glad you finally got it uninstalled! That command was also in the first web site link that I gave you in chat.

Answer (score 2):

In the `terminal`, `sudo dpkg -P code` should do it... although the gdebi `Uninstall` option should have worked for you too. Why do you wish to uninstall it, as it's a good editor, especially for source code.

**Update #1:**

Since `Code` had been installed using `umake`, it required `sudo umake --remove ide visual-studio-code` to uninstall it properly.

Comment: I just want to install the updated version :-)

And using that command option is not working. I got output saying - `Purging configuration files for code` but then when I clicked VSCode launcher it opened successfully.

Comment: You can install the newer version right over the old version... or if you've got a current enough version of `Code`, you can just go to the `Help` menu an select `Check for Updates`.

Comment: `Check for Updates` takes me to download page. And installing newer version does not uninstall the old one.

Comment: Installing the newer version should overwrite the old version. In your Unity dashboard, if you type `code`, do you get TWO icons that show up?

Comment: You can try `sudo dpkg -P visual-studio-code`.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/6NNt5 see the 2 icons here

Comment: Output of 2nd command - `dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove visual-studio-code which isn't installed
`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63672/discussion-between-takias-and-heynnema).

Comment: @takias  See my comments in chat...

Answer (score 2):

On my Ubuntu 18.10, I installed vscode as a snap.
I was able to remove it with:

```
sudo snap remove vscode
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu and for your interest in this site.  Unfortunately, the original post did not indicate that snap was used to install the package so snap remove isn't going to be useful.

Comment: if you use this then work fine in ubuntu 20.04 LTS
sudo snap remove code